# Is a SortedList or SortedDictionary the best way to efficiently store and retrieve data by the nearest key?

Tags: optimization, data-structures, binary-search-tree, sortedlist, sorteddictionary

I am working on a project where I'm storing an object inside a SortedList<float, myData> with timestamps as a key so that I can use the built in binary search to retrieve the data (or two sets if the lower and higher bounds are equally distant from the key) that was stored closest to any given timestamp. For context, the insertion and retrieval occur every 2ms on average (it's for a game replay/rewind function essentially, I'm just storing the current state of entities). And while it works, it's not super efficient with it's O(n) insertion. I know SortedDictionary has an O(log n) insertion, but no built in binary search.

Is there a better option for my situation that you more experienced folks may know of? The ultimate goal of what I'm looking for is a way to do the following:

1. Save data in sequence of timestamp
2. Get data flanking any given timestamp (I lerp between for interval values)
3. "Replay" data starting from given timestamp (so #2 in rapid succession)
4. Clear any data from before or after a given timestamp

From what I've seen and understood, SortedList wins for #2 (and #3 by proxy) and SortedDictionary is best at number 1 and I'd have to roll my own BinarySearch for it to even do #2/3.
At the moment each entity is handling it's own SortedList, though I wonder if making a sort of RecordManager with a single structure to handle all entities might be more performant.

Any help or suggestions would be great!

Comment: Why do you need _#2 in rapid succession_ for #3? With a data structure which allows to get the next entry, you wouldn't have to search repeatedly, but just compare the entry's timestamp to the interval's end.

Comment: @Armali The problem is potential frame skippage where it's not the next entry but a few entries later

Comment: If _few_ next entries are to be skipped, this can easily and also more efficiently be done by examining the next entries rather than re-searching the whole dataset, even if binary.